# If condition to check for DBNull.Value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check for `DBNull.Value` but in this case `reader["Preferences"]` returns {} in the immediate window (why?)

so when  `(string)reader["Preferences"];` executes I get a type casting error

```
if (reader["Preferences"] == System.DBNull.Value)
{
     preferences = (string)reader["Preferences"];
}
```

Comment: you can directly you Convert.ToString() instead of this. it handles the dbnull values

Comment: personally, I strongly advocate using `reader.ISDBNull(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cast only when the value *is* `DBNull.Value`.

You should invert your `if`:

```
if (reader["Preferences"] != System.DBNull.Value)
{
     preferences = (string)reader["Preferences"];
}
```